# How to count number of observations based on another variable values that are divided by ranges

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to count number of observations based on another variable values that are divided by ranges. I was able to group the first variable (birds) and I was able to count its number of observations,however when I tried to get the number of observations for the second variable I got wrong answers as I show below.How can I overcome this issue?

Here Is my data frame sample:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "  birds    wolfs     snakes
                           2        9         7
                           90       8         4
                           90       2         8
                           100      2         3
                           100      8         3
                           660      1         2
                           660      7         1
                           660      1         5
                           500      9         7
                           30       8         7
                           40       2         7
                           10       2         3
                           70       6         3
                           60       1         1
                           60       3         9
                           60       1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

I ran this line of code to get the groups:

```
dat$birdsrange <- cut(dat$birds, breaks=seq(0, 1000, 25))
```

Than I added two code lines:

```
dat$mbirds <- with(dat, ave(birds, birdsrange, FUN=length))
dat$mwolfs <- with(dat, ave(wolfs, birdsrange, FUN=length))
```

So I got this output:

```
   birds wolfs snakes birdsrange mbirds mwolfs
1      2     9      7     (0,25]      2      2
2     90     8      4   (75,100]      4      4
3     90     2      8   (75,100]      4      4
4    100     2      3   (75,100]      4      4
5    100     8      3   (75,100]      4      4
6    660     1      2  (650,675]      3      3
7    660     7      1  (650,675]      3      3
8    660     1      5  (650,675]      3      3
9    500     9      7  (475,500]      1      1
10    30     8      7    (25,50]      2      2
11    40     2      7    (25,50]      2      2
12    10     2      3     (0,25]      2      2
13    70     6      3    (50,75]      4      4
14    60     1      1    (50,75]      4      4
15    60     3      9    (50,75]      4      4
16    60     1      1    (50,75]      4      4
```

The "mbirds" count is good however the "mwolfs" is bad as I expected to get 16 observation for the group: (0,25] and "0" for the other groups.How can I solve the problem?
the desired outcome should be:

```
range mbirds mwolfs
(0,25]  2      16
(25,50] 2      0
(50,75] 4      0
```

...

Comment: Why do you expect mwolfs to be 16? I dont quite understand

Comment: @beginneR, because there are no rows that contain more than 25 wolves

Comment: That's right @David Arenburg

Comment: But your code is based on the birdsrange (also for mwolfs).. so that's the problem, it seems?

Comment: Yes indeed @ beginneR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to tabulate. You can use `sapply` together with `table` to get your desired result.

```
res <- sapply(dat, function(x){
  table(cut(x, breaks=seq(0,1000,25)))
})
head(res)
##           birds wolfs snakes
## (0,25]        2    16     16
## (25,50]       2     0      0
## (50,75]       4     0      0
## (75,100]      4     0      0
## (100,125]     0     0      0
## (125,150]     0     0      0
```

Comment: Thank you @shadow but I get an error "Error in cut.default(x, breaks = seq(0, 1000, 25)) : 'x' must be numeric". Another thing: how can I evoid the "snakes" variable in the output?.

Comment: I guess you ran this code after creating `cut$birdsrange`? Try running it before...

Comment: you can use `dat[, c('birds', 'wolfs')]` instead of `dat`.